# Using a constant in multiple freemarker templates

Tags: freemarker

I'm using Freemarker templates to generate HTML. I have this line repeated in several templates:

```
<link href="/css/main.css?v=${css_version}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I want to be able to specify a value for css_version just once, and use it in all my templates. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly like this:

```
Configuration cfg ...
...
cfg.setSharedVariable("css_version", "1.2.3");
```

Note that you should do this where you set up your singleton `Configuration` instance, and it's not thread safe to call `setSharedVariable` later. So if `css_version` has to change without recreating the `Configuration`, then instead of a `String` simply use a custom `TemplateScalarModel` implementation that reads the version number from some thread-safe source. (That is, the value of a shared value can change over time, as far as the template sees it, even though the actual shared variable object isn't replaced.)